# java index of selected item arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, indexof

In Java, I'm trying to identify which JComboBox within an ArrayList was just clicked on.  Some of the code follows:

```
private ArrayList<JComboBox<String>>    setTextBoxList;

// basic initialization
public void populateList() {
    String str[] = {"one", "two"};
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        JComboBox<String> jcb = new JComboBox<String>(str);
        setTextBoxList.add(new JComboBox<String>(str));
        jcb.addActionListener(this);
    }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object o = e.getSource();
    if(o instanceof JComboBox) {
        // here's where I'd like to see which box was just changed
        System.out.println("change index "
            + setTextBoxList.indexOf((JComboBox)o) );
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I click on and change one of the comboboxes, the index shown is always -1.  I'd like to get the index of which box in the arraylist was just clicked on/changed. I get the same results w/o the explicit type-cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this segment of code:

```
for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    JComboBox<String> jcb = new JComboBox<String>(str);
    setTextBoxList.add(new JComboBox<String>(str)); // <-- error!
    jcb.addActionListener(this);
}
```

You are creating two `JComboBox`es, and the one that gets the listener is not the one that is in the list. Try changing the code to:

```
for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    JComboBox<String> jcb = new JComboBox<String>(str);
    setTextBoxList.add(jcb); // changed line
    jcb.addActionListener(this);
}
```

Comment: Duh! Yes, that's the problem.  So sorry to have bothered you all with this.  Ugggh, feeling pretty stupid right now but greatly appreciate your help.  Thanks so much!